# pretty html highlighting using <span>

Tags: html, css, highlighting

I'm highlighting text in a HTML document using `<span>` tags around the content to be highlighted.  The span class has a `background-color` defined, and a `border-radius` is also set.  This works well.

I'd like the highlight to extend a bit further beyond the normal extents of the `<span>` content.  That is, a few pixels to the left of the span-start, and a few pixels to the right of the span-end.  Ideally I'd do this without spacing apart the content itself.

Any good css tricks I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Margin? padding? Not sure I understoof what you're looking for ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a padding and a negative margin. For example:

```
span {
    margin: -5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u767S/).**

Comment: Thanks - that was much simpler than I thought.  I'm clearly not a css wizard ;)

Comment: If the margin/padding is increased too much, say 10px, the span begins to clip the preceeding content.  Is there any way to alleviate this?

Comment: @TomSwift: Add `position: relative;` and `z-index: -1;`.

Answer (score 0):

margin: 10px 0px; ??

if this does not solve your issue can you elaborate on the problem ?

Comment: just a note, *margin* doesn't work that way, no commas between values.