# highlighting by div behind text

Tags: css, html, dom, z-index

I'd like to do text highlighting by hovering a `div` behind the text via z-index*.  If the element containing the text doesn't have a background, it works fine:

[image]

However, if the element has a `background` or `background-color`, it doesn't work as the background blocks the view of the div that's behind it:

[image]

Of course I can make the div be on top, but that looks terrible, as it colors the text itself:

[image]

You can see this problem in action with jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paleozogt/V3Kae/).  My question is: how can I have a `div` go *behind* the text but *above* the background?

---

* Why am I not using a `span` like [everyone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149542/pretty-html-highlighting-using-span)?  Because with `div` I can animate the highlighting's movement from word to word.  That's in the jsfiddle also.

Comment: The sample doesn't work too well in Chrome. When clicking "move [direction]", the hilighting div does move, but it leaves behind artifacts.

Comment: What if you made the background somewhat transparent with rgba?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that's odd. it animates fine for me in chrome20/FF14/IE9.

Comment: @sachleen That sort of works.  Unfortunately, I don't have control over how the bg color is done.

Comment: @paleozogt You won't be able to position an element between the text and its background color. You can try having another div that is there just to provide a bg color. Then you can position your element between the text (no bg) and the blank div (bg). Btw, I also see the artifacts.

Comment: @sachleen alas, i don't have control over how the page is constructed

Comment: @sachleen what os/browser are you using to view the fiddle? i wonder if this is a browser bug or a jquery bug?

Comment: If you can only control the highlight div, your best bet is to try to find a color/opacity combination that doesn't look ugly.

Comment: It's happening on Chrome 21.0.1180.60 m, Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: @paleozogt it's not a jQuery bug.. just a rendering issue. If you select text, resize the window, it goes away. Chrome 21, Win7

Comment: @sachleen the fiddle is structured as you suggest. no bg on the text, only on the parent div. see my version of the fiddle below, i did not touch anything, except adding a few lines of css...

Comment: There seems be a rendering bug in chrome, anybody else seeing this? When the box move left, I get lots of lines left over from the animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/V3Kae/9/
you could do it like this. setting the z-index of the container to be lower then the highlight, an the z-index of the text to be higher then the highlight.

Comment: This is the way to go.  Also, take special note of the `position:relative` with the `z-index` on the `bg` and `content` elements.  Without it, the `z-index` would have no effect.